# What happens when an AC source is connected to a capacitor and a LED?

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, light-emitting-diodes

When a DC source is connected to a capacitor and a LED, and the voltage is removed when capacitor is charged, the capacitor supplies current to it for some time. What happens if this DC source is changed to AC source. Don't hate.:)

Comment: It is an RC circuit. The LED acts as a resistance.

Comment: @YashasSamaga can you please tell me more about these RC circuits. Thank you for your answer

Comment: The question is too broad. Refer to some textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because an LED acts like a diode, the negative current from the AC source will be clipped and the capacitor will always be charged and it will act like a second voltage source. Look at my picture below. You can see that the green line represents the voltage going through the capacitor and the blue line (it's a little hard to see since it's covered up by the green line) is behaving the same way as it represents the voltage across the LED (or the output voltage).
[image]

Comment: This app is called EveryCircuit and it's available on Android and iOS.

Comment: Sure thing! Make sure and ask these types of questions on the Electrical Engineering SE. I'll also be there as well!